# c# MVC Dropdownlist - There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key ' '

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, html-select

Ive just been trying to expand on a previous project by adding a DropDownList on to  home/contact.cshtml.

My issue is i keep receiving the following error when loading the page in firefox

Error:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'displayGraph'

I have another dropdownlist on another page that works fine(same method), if I copy the same code into a new project it works fine, could anyone advise me what could cause this?

contact.cshtml - code snippet

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Filter By: @Html.DropDownList("displayGraph","Select a Graph")                
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        </p>            
    }
```

HomeController - Code Snippet

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string chart1 = "Num Each Model Processed", chart2 = "Another chart to be assigned";
        var GraphLst = new List<string> { chart1, chart1 };
        ViewBag.displayGraph = new SelectList(GraphLst);

        string userName = User.Identity.Name;
        return View();
    }
```

Graphdropdownmodel - code snippet

```
   namespace TestSolution.Models
 {
      public class GraphDropdownModel
    {   
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Graph{ get; set; }
    }
    public class GraphDBContext : DbContext
    {
    public DbSet<GraphDropdownModel> Graphs { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The above works as is for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/JR3iFy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using @Html.DropDownListFor

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.value, (SelectList)ViewBag.displayGraph)
```

Comment: Ok I think the above has pointed out what is missing Ive just created a model which Ive added above,Thanks for your input Wozone but I cant select model => model.Graph, I'm assuming this has something to do with my model not being configured correctly?

Comment: For DropDownListFor the first property is the variable that will contain the option selected by the user. Typically this is the ID of the Graph. You could change you model to include the graph ID. Assuming there is an ID.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `ViewBag` is a dynamic property, and the `DropDownList` can't figure out that it has to cast the actual type (which is `SelectList`) to an `IEnuerable<SelectListItem>` for the conversion operator to work.

However, this is probably a good thing because even if you did get it to work, you would be headed for trouble.  As soon as you tried to post back the data to the server, the MVC model binder would get confused because you would now have an item in the `ModelState` called `displayGraph` which is of type `SelectList` and you are also posting string value with the name of `displayGraph`.

This is why using a `DropDownListFor()` is better (or at least using the overload of `DropDownList()` that takes a separate property name and collection list).

Always name your selected property different from the collection you use to populate your dropdown, it will save you a lot of headaches.